# iOS Developer Account - 50GB iCloud space still available. Will it go away?

Tags: icloud, ios, developer-program

I have an iOS developer account for which 50GB of space on iCloud Drive (or whatever the overall service is called these days) was allocated, when I installed iOS 8.0 beta on one of my devices (an iPhone).

When iOS 8.0 released to the public I got an email saying that my 50GB limit was to be withdrawn.

But it hasn't happened and I can still see that much available (I don't have a paid plan - I'm only eligible for 5GB). Secondly, perhaps for this reason, iCloud Photo library has been available on all my devices since installing iOS 8.0, (the iPhone which was last updated to the iOS 8.0 GM Seed, and the other, an iPad, which went from iOS 7.0.x to 8.0.2 directly upon public release of 8.0.2)  whereas if I understand correctly, it is only being made available to the public since iOS 8.1.

My question is - is this a glitch or have other developers (consistently, and broadly) experienced the same thing? Will this storage space (and more importantly all the data I store in it - if I were to) go away suddenly?

Would I be better off contacting Apple Support to make sure this error (if any) is corrected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of the mail who sent apple regarding this:

> Your complimentary 50 GB of iCloud storage is expiring on November 1st and your account will be downgraded to your original storage plan. If you are using more storage than your original iCloud storage plan, you need to upgrade your plan or reduce the amount of storage you're using. You can view your storage used and upgrade your plan from your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, or Mac.

So, it will expire in a few days. Did not say anything about how will they do if you are over quota, just tell you to upgrade or free space.

Comment: Ah. Speaks to my poor memory of it then. Thanks for quoting the mail.